# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException-at ButtonSensor.actionPerformed(NameWindow.java:21)

Tags: java, awt

I am trying to solve a problem where it is stated that i should get the value from a `textfield`(in this case a name) in a frame and put *Hello* in front of it then print it again in the frame.

Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
class NameWindow{
    public static void main(String str[]){
        MyFrame mf=new MyFrame();
        mf.setVisible(true);
    }
}
class WindowSensor extends WindowAdapter{
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we){
        System.out.println("Window is closing");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
class ButtonSensor implements ActionListener{
    MyFrame mf;
    public ButtonSensor(MyFrame f){
        mf=f;
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
        String name=mf.tf.getText();
        mf.setMessage("Hello"+name);
        mf.repaint();
    }
}

class MyFrame extends Frame{
    private String msg;
    public TextField tf;
    public MyFrame(){
        super("Java Name Window");
        msg="Enter Your Name:";
        Button b=new Button("Say Hello!");
        TextField tf=new TextField(20);
        ButtonSensor bs=new ButtonSensor(this);
        WindowSensor ws=new WindowSensor();
        add(tf);
        add(b);
        addWindowListener(ws);
        b.addActionListener(bs);
        setSize(600,400);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    }
    public void setMessage(String s){
        msg=s;
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        g.drawString(msg,30,50);
    }
}
```

Comment: why AWT and not in Swing

Comment: probably ButtonSensor bs=new ButtonSensor(this); has referrence to the black hole

Comment: The error is showing in line number 21 that is:
`String name=mf.tf.getText();`
any idea about this? Thanks anyway

Comment: Looks like the problem was in the line:
`TextField tf=new TextField(20);`
Because I have already declared a TextField named tf in the same class,thus the null pointer exception. Correct one will be like:
`tf=new TextField(20);` 
Thanks mKorbel anyway man :)

Comment: You could write about the solution in the answer box provided below the question. This is better than editing the word "solved" into the title. You can also get rewarded for having an answer....